# Prove that this function has finite variation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, bounded-variation

We know that $f$ has finite variation on $[a,b]$.

Prove that $$g(x)= \begin{cases} 0, & x=a\\[8pt]  \frac{1}{x-a} \int _{a} ^x f(t) \, dt , & x \in (a,b] \end{cases} $$

has finite variation.

I would really appreciate all your help, because I'm just starting my course in integral calculus.

Thank you.

Comment: Of course there should be $a$, I'm sorry.

Comment: You can use alignment tabs within "cases".  See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

The function $g$ is absolutely continuous on any interval $[c,b]$ with $a < c < b$. Try to use this fact along with a bound on $|g(c) - g(a)| = |g(c)|$.

Answer (score 1):

Since $f$ is of bounded variation, you can write it $f=f_1-f_2$ where $f_1,f_2$ are non decreasing. It suffices to prove that

$$g_i(x)= \begin{cases} 0, & x=a\\[8pt]  \frac{1}{x-a} \int _{a} ^x f_i(t) \, dt , & x \in (a,b] \end{cases}$$

are of bounded variation.

Since $f_i$ is non decreasing, there exists some $c_i$ so that $f_i(x) < 0 \forall x < c_i$ and $f_i(x) \geq 0 \forall x \geq c_i$. Then $g_i$ is either [ decreasing on $[a, c_i]$ and increasing on $[c_i,b]$] or strictly monotonic on $[a,b]$ depending if $c_i \in (a,b)$.

In particular $g_i$ is of bounded variation.

Comment: Ok, I see that. Could you explain to me what to do next? I don't quite see how to use bounded variation of $g_1, \ \ g_2$ to prove that $g$ is of bounded variation.

Comment: @Sandy You can probably prove directly that the variation of $g$ is less or equal then the sum of the variations of $g_1$ and $g_2$. Or even easier, write each of $g_1,g_2$ as the difference of two non-decreasing functions, and then combine them the right way to get $g$ as the difference of two non-decreasing functions.

Comment: Could you tell me what do I do to combine the differences in order to get $g$ as the difference of two increasing functions? I mean, is there any relationship between $g_1, \ g_2$ that I can use?

Comment: @Sandy $g_1=h_2-h_2$ and $g_2=h_3-h_4$ then $g_1-g_2=h_1-h_2-h_3+h_4$, with all four non-decreasing. Since the sum of two non-decreasing function is non-decreasing, how can you get $g$ as the difference of two non-decreasing functions? ;)

Comment: I'm not sure if it correct, but could it be that for $x \in (a, b]$ we have  $g(x) = \frac{1}{x-a} \int _{a} ^x f(t) \, dt = \frac{1}{x-a} \int _{a} ^x (f_1(t) - f_2(t)) \, dt = g_1(x) - g_2(x) = h_1+h_4-(h_2+h_3)$ ? So we have $g$ presented as a difference of two increasing functions.

Comment: All right :) Thank you a lot.

Comment: I have just one more question. I'm not sure I understand why $g_i$ has bounded variation, I mean why is it decreasing on $[a,c_i]$ and increasing on $[c_i,b]$ or strictly monotone. Could you explain that?

Comment: @Sandy If $f_i >0$ on some interval then $g_i$ is increasing on that interval. And if $f_i < 0$ then $g_i$ is decreasing

Comment: Well, but doesn't the $\frac{1}{x-a}$ influence the value of the integral in some way?

Comment: It does. But if $h$ is positive and increasing then for all $x <y$ you have $\int_a^x f(t)dt  \leq f(x) (x-a)$ while $\int_x^y f(t)dt  \geq f (x) (y-x)$. From here you should be able to prove that $\frac{1}{x-a}\int_a^x f(t)dt  \leq \frac{1}{y-a}\int_a^y f(t)dt$. Just write $\frac{1}{y-a}\int_a^y f(t)dt= \frac{1}{y-a}\int_a^x f(t)dt+ \frac{1}{y-a}\int_x^y f(t)dt$ and simplify the inequality you need to prove....